# Injetar token no header de todas as requisições http

Tags: angular, ionic2

Estou tentando criar um método geral para inserir um token em todas as minhas requisições http. Não entendo muito de angular 2 mas fiz da maneira abaixo:

> Arquivo `generic-service.ts`

```
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Session} from '@enterpiseCustomLib';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class GenericService {
  public urlWs: string = 'http://trix.example.com:8090/';
  private http: Http;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  get(method) {
    return this.http.get(this.urlWs + method, {
      headers: this.getHeaders()
    }).map(res => res.json());
  }

  post(method, data) {
    return this.http.post(this.urlWs + method, data, {
      headers: this.getHeaders()
    }).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getHeaders() {
    try {
      let user = Session.get('loginModel');
      let defaultHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
      defaultHeaders.append('Token', user.token);
      return defaultHeaders;
    } catch (ex) {
      return new Headers();
    }
  }

}
```

> Arquivo `login-service.ts`

```
import {GenericService} from './generic-service';
import {LoginModel} from '../model/login-model';

export class LoginService {

  private gs: GenericService;

  constructor(gs:GenericService) {
    this.gs = gs;
  }

  public verificaUsuario (usuario: LoginModel) {
    return this.gs.post('login/autenticar', JSON.stringify(usuario));
  }

}
```

> Arquivo `login.ts`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginModel} from '../../model/login-model';
import {LoginService} from '../../services/login-service';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Alertar} from '@enterpiseCustomLib';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.login = new LoginModel();
    this.login.email = 'teste@teste.com';
    this.login.senha = '123';
  }

  startLogin() {
    this.loginService.verificaUsuario(this.login).subscribe(resposta => {
      console.log(resposta);
    });
  }
}
```

Na hora que vou fazer os testes tenho o erro abaixo:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for LoginService!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:1691:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:26882:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:26919:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27907:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27935:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27898:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27707:21)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29281:48)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:29281:48)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:27932:24)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que um dos problemas é que seu serviço LoginService não esta usando a annotation de injeção de dependência, e você não a instancia em nenhum lugar no seu component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoginService {
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, é isso mesmo.